# Optimize objects display (gamedev)

Tags: python, pygame

Relevant code, simplified :

```py
class Character:
    def __init__(self):
        self.projectiles = []

    def shoot(self):
        self.projectiles.append(Projectile())

    def draw(self):
        for projectile in self.projectiles:
            pygame.draw.rect()  # args do not seem relevant here
```

`draw()` very slows the game down whenever there is a projectile spawned.

My questions :
Can I speed up the list iteration process ?
Can I implement a better way than a list ?
Where could I put some multi-threading in this ?

**Edit :**

`shoot()` is called once per frame at most (triggered upon keybinding), and the `projectiles` list is iterated on twice (update and draw steps).

The game gets very laggy with a single projectile, and gets fluid again when the projectiles reach a certain distance (map limits) and are removed from the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I speed up the list iteration process?

No, but maybe you iterate too many times over the list than necessary. How big is `projectiles` when you call `draw()`?

> Can I implement a better way than a list?

When using pygame, you should consider using the `Sprite` and `Group` classes. Use a `Group` instead of a list. This offers some convenient functionality, like drawing your sprites on different layers, abstracting the updating and drawing, and easy removing of sprites with `kill()` etc.

> Where could I put some multi-threading in this?

I'm 99.9% sure you don't actually need multi-threading.

---

Your problem is the update method of your `Projectile` class:

```
def update(self, camera):
    self.posW += self.speed * self.dirW * Clock().tick(FPS)
    self.posH += self.speed * self.dirH * Clock().tick(FPS)
    self.rect = (self.posW, self.posH, 20, 20)
```

Here you create a new `Clock` instance and call `tick` twice per frame for each `Projectile` instance, which will pause your game mutliple times per frame.

What you should do is to create a `Clock` instance once, and call only once `tick` per frame, and pass the resulting value down to your sprites to adjust their speed.

---

I changed your code to make use of game's `Sprite` class and removed a lot of files:

camera.py:

```
import pygame

class CameraAwareLayeredUpdates(pygame.sprite.LayeredUpdates):
    def __init__(self, target, world_size, screen_size):
        super().__init__()
        self.target = target
        self.cam = pygame.Vector2(0, 0)
        self.world_size = world_size
        self.screen_size = screen_size
        if self.target:
            self.add(target)

    def update(self, *args):
        super().update(*args)

        if self.target:
            x = -self.target.rect.center[0] + self.screen_size[0]/2
            y = -self.target.rect.center[1] + self.screen_size[1]/2
            self.cam += (pygame.Vector2((x, y)) - self.cam) * 0.07
            self.cam.x = max(-(self.world_size[0]-self.screen_size[0]), min(0, self.cam.x))
            self.cam.y = max(-(self.world_size[1]-self.screen_size[1]), min(0, self.cam.y))

    def draw(self, surface):
        spritedict = self.spritedict
        surface_blit = surface.blit
        dirty = self.lostsprites
        self.lostsprites = []
        dirty_append = dirty.append
        init_rect = self._init_rect
        for spr in self.sprites():
            rec = spritedict[spr]
            newrect = surface_blit(spr.image, spr.rect.move(self.cam))
            if rec is init_rect:
                dirty_append(newrect)
            else:
                if newrect.colliderect(rec):
                    dirty_append(newrect.union(rec))
                else:
                    dirty_append(newrect)
                    dirty_append(rec)
            spritedict[spr] = newrect
        return dirty
```

game.py:

```
import pygame

from lib.camera import CameraAwareLayeredUpdates

TILESIZE = 50
WORLD_SIZE_IN_TILES = 30, 16
WORLD_SIZE = [v*TILESIZE for v in WORLD_SIZE_IN_TILES]
SCREEN_SIZE = 800, 500

class Actor(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, game, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args)
        self.game = game

        self.image = pygame.Surface(kwargs.get('size', (50, 50)))
        self.image.fill(pygame.Color(kwargs.get('color', 'blue')))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.pos = pygame.Vector2(kwargs.get('pos', self.rect.center))
        self.rect.center = [int(x) for x in self.pos]
        self.vel = pygame.Vector2(kwargs.get('vel', (0, 0)))

    def update(self, dt, events):
        self.pos += (self.vel * dt/10)
        self.rect.center = [int(x) for x in self.pos]

class Character(Actor):
    def __init__(self, game, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(game, *args, **kwargs)
        self.facing = pygame.Vector2(0, 1)

    def update(self, dt, events):
        for event in events:
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                    self.game.add(Actor, 
                            pos=self.rect.center, 
                            vel=self.facing * 10,
                            color='blue',
                            size=(20, 20))

        pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        self.vel.x, self.vel.y = 0, 0
        if pressed[pygame.K_a]: self.vel.x = -1
        if pressed[pygame.K_d]: self.vel.x = 1
        if pressed[pygame.K_w]: self.vel.y = -1
        if pressed[pygame.K_s]: self.vel.y = 1
        if self.vel.length() > 0:
            self.facing = pygame.Vector2(self.vel)
            self.facing.normalize_ip()
        self.vel *= 5

        super().update(dt, events)

class Tilemap(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self._layer = -100
        self.tilesH = WORLD_SIZE_IN_TILES[1]
        self.tilesW = WORLD_SIZE_IN_TILES[0]
        self.map = [
            'white' for i in range(self.tilesH * self.tilesW)
        ]

        for i in range(self.tilesH):
            for j in range(self.tilesW):
                if i * j == 0 or i == self.tilesH - 1 or j == self.tilesW - 1:
                    self.map[i * j] = 'grey'

        self.image = self.render()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

    def update(self, *args):
        pass

    def render(self):
        surf = pygame.Surface(WORLD_SIZE)
        for i in range(self.tilesH):
            for j in range(self.tilesW):
                rect = (j * TILESIZE, i * TILESIZE, TILESIZE, TILESIZE)
                pygame.draw.rect(surf, pygame.Color(self.map[i * j]), rect)
        return surf

class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.init()
        pygame.display.set_caption("SANTARENA")
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode(SCREEN_SIZE)
        self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        player = Character(self, color='red', pos=self.screen.get_rect().center)
        self.all_sprites = CameraAwareLayeredUpdates(player, WORLD_SIZE, SCREEN_SIZE)
        self.all_sprites.add(Tilemap())

    def add(self, clazz, **kwargs):
        instance = clazz(self, self.all_sprites, **kwargs)
        return instance

    def start(self):
        dt = 0
        while True:
            events = pygame.event.get()
            for event in events:
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    return

            self.all_sprites.update(dt, events)
            self.all_sprites.draw(self.screen)
            pygame.display.update()
            dt = self.clock.tick(60)
```

[image]

Comment: I will definitely check those classes out. It might very well solve my issue, yet I still updated the question.

Comment: @Pypaut Are your projectiles just rects? It seems strange that a single one will cause a lag. Maybe post your full code (if it isn't too much).

Comment: Is it okay to just link my [repo](https://github.com/pypaut/santarena) ? `python/lib/*`.

Comment: I am certainly not used to the Python way yet. Impressive! I look forward to update it all. Thank you!